# Merge consecutive and overlapping date ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm hoping someone here can help me.  I have tried just about every web search I can think of but I can't seem to find info that will help me get what I'm looking for.

I have several datasets where customer service periods are consecutive or overlap, similar to the below.

```
import pandas as pd 
cust = ['CUST123', 'CUST123', 'CUST123', 'CUST123', 'CUST456', 'CUST456']
start_date = ['01/01/2021','01/07/2021','01/15/2021','02/02/2021','01/05/2021','01/16/2021']
end_date = ['01/11/2021','01/14/2021','01/31/2021','02/28/2021','01/15/2021','01/31/2021']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(cust, start_date, end_date)), columns = ['cust', 'start_date', 'end_date'])
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])
```

[image: have dataset]

What I need to do is collapse overlapping or consecutive date ranges such that I'm left with only continuous service periods afterward :

[image: need dataset]

I have a SAS program that does this and has served me well for the past 10 years or so but sadly my company is ditching SAS for Python at the end of 2022 and I'm scrambling to port many years of SAS code before then.

The SAS program even has the ability to set a variable as to how much time (in days) could exist between end dates and start dates in order to be considered consecutive.  So for instance, using the above examples, if I had set the variable to 2, there would have only been 1 output row for CUST123 since 2/2/21 is within 2 days of 1/31/21.

At this point any help or guidance would be happily accepted.  I'm very lost at the moment.

**Update:**

I'm so close, but I can't quite seem to get all the way there.
Given the origin dataframe below I modified the original code shared as:

```
df.groupby(["cust","service_tier"], as_index=False).apply(
    lambda d: d.sort_values(["cust", "service_tier", "start_date", "end_date"])
    .groupby(
        ["cust", "service_tier", (~(d["start_date"] <= (d["end_date"].shift() + pd.Timedelta(days=3)))).cumsum()],
        as_index=False
    )
    .agg({"start_date": "min", "end_date": "max"})
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Origin DataFrame:**

```
       cust  service_tier start_date   end_date
0   CUST123             1 2020-06-13 2020-06-27
1   CUST123             1 2020-06-15 2020-07-13
2   CUST123             1 2020-06-22 2020-07-23
3   CUST123             1 2020-06-24 2020-07-08
4   CUST123             1 2020-07-13 2020-07-27
5   CUST123             1 2020-08-20 2020-09-17
6   CUST123             1 2020-08-21 2020-09-04
7   CUST123             1 2020-08-25 2020-09-05
8   CUST123             1 2020-08-27 2020-09-21
9   CUST123             1 2020-09-01 2020-10-05
10  CUST123             1 2020-09-10 2020-09-17
11  CUST123             1 2020-10-05 2020-11-30
12  CUST123             1 2020-12-01 2021-05-31
13  CUST123             1 2021-06-01 2021-11-30
14  CUST456             1 2021-01-05 2021-01-15
15  CUST456             2 2021-01-16 2021-01-31
```

**The modified code however gets me this:**

```
      cust  service_tier start_date   end_date
0  CUST123             1 2020-06-13 2020-07-23
1  CUST123             1 2020-07-13 2020-07-27
2  CUST123             1 2020-08-20 2020-10-05
3  CUST123             1 2020-10-05 2021-11-30
4  CUST456             1 2021-01-05 2021-01-15
5  CUST456             2 2021-01-16 2021-01-31
```

When it really should be this:

```
      cust  service_tier start_date   end_date
0  CUST123             1 2020-06-13 2020-07-27
1  CUST123             1 2020-08-20 2021-11-30
2  CUST456             1 2021-01-05 2021-01-15
3  CUST456             2 2021-01-16 2021-01-31
```

I think it's because the code doesn't take into account when a date range is entirely contained within a prior date range.
I've been trying to figure out how to update the "***(~(d["start_date"] <= (d["end_date"].shift() + pd.Timedelta(days=3))))***" part with multiple conditions, but I'm failing miserably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- within customer `groupby("cust", as_index=False)` look for overlapping dates in rows
- `cumsum()` sums booleans to generate a group for overlapping dates
- finally simple case on min/max within groups

```
df.groupby("cust", as_index=False).apply(
    lambda d: d.sort_values(["start_date", "end_date"])
    .groupby(
        ["cust", (~(d["start_date"] <= (d["end_date"].shift() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)))).cumsum()],
        as_index=False
    )
    .agg({"start_date": "min", "end_date": "max"})
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

|  | cust | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | CUST123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-31 00:00:00 |
| 1 | CUST123 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00 | 2021-02-28 00:00:00 |
| 2 | CUST456 | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 2021-01-31 00:00:00 |

#### supplementary update

- this works by testing row by row with previous row.  Hence `sort_order()` is critical
- this actually requires ordering by **end_date** then **start_date**
- have created a new column as I realised order was being ignored !  This column can be dropped in final data frame
- worked this out by working with just main group before amending code in `groupby()` **lambda** function

**debug code**

```
df.loc[df["cust"].eq("CUST123")].sort_values(["end_date", "start_date"]).assign(
    grp=lambda d: (
        ~(d["start_date"] <= (d["end_date"].shift() + pd.Timedelta(days=3)))
    ).cumsum()
)
```

**final solution**

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""       cust  service_tier start_date   end_date
0   CUST123             1 2020-06-13 2020-06-27
1   CUST123             1 2020-06-15 2020-07-13
2   CUST123             1 2020-06-22 2020-07-23
3   CUST123             1 2020-06-24 2020-07-08
4   CUST123             1 2020-07-13 2020-07-27
5   CUST123             1 2020-08-20 2020-09-17
6   CUST123             1 2020-08-21 2020-09-04
7   CUST123             1 2020-08-25 2020-09-05
8   CUST123             1 2020-08-27 2020-09-21
9   CUST123             1 2020-09-01 2020-10-05
10  CUST123             1 2020-09-10 2020-09-17
11  CUST123             1 2020-10-05 2020-11-30
12  CUST123             1 2020-12-01 2021-05-31
13  CUST123             1 2021-06-01 2021-11-30
14  CUST456             1 2021-01-05 2021-01-15
15  CUST456             2 2021-01-16 2021-01-31"""), sep="\s+")

df = df.assign(**{c:pd.to_datetime(df[c]) for c in df.columns if "date" in c})

df.groupby(["cust", "service_tier"], as_index=False).apply(
    lambda d: d.sort_values(["end_date", "start_date"])
    .assign(
        grp=lambda d: (
            ~(d["start_date"] <= (d["end_date"].shift() + pd.Timedelta(days=3)))
        ).cumsum()
    )
    .groupby(["cust", "service_tier", "grp"], as_index=False)
    .agg({"start_date": "min", "end_date": "max"})
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I totally would not have figured this out so quickly.  This solution is so nice and compact.  Quick question, Could I use a variable in place of the number 1 in "pd.Timedelta(days=1)" to have a dynamic amount of time (in days) between end dates and start dates to be considered consecutive?  It looks like I can, but I don't completely know if that will break anything if I do it.

Comment: if for example, end_date if Friday and start_date is Monday,  then there would be 3 days offset. If Monday is a public holiday,  it would become 4...  it's not really dynamic (situationally aware of weekends or public holidays) but can be set to a different static offset

Comment: Hi @rob-raymond, I've added some updates based upon my application of the code snippet you so graciously shared.  I thank you for that and was wondering if you had any thought regarding the new wrinkle I've mentioned in my update.

Comment: Worked for the last example but now one cust's data that was fine before isnt. 2 date ranges for CUST789 when it should be 1.

   cust  service_tier start_date   end_date
CUST789             1 2020-11-04 2020-12-30
CUST789             1 2020-11-16 2020-12-13
CUST789             1 2020-12-14 2022-01-10
CUST789             1 2021-01-11 2022-02-07
CUST789             1 2021-02-08 2021-03-07
CUST789             1 2021-03-08 2021-05-02
CUST789             1 2021-04-26 2021-05-07
CUST456             1 2021-01-05 2021-01-15
CUST456             2 2021-01-16 2021-01-31

Comment: hmmm - permutations ... one of the options I considered,  was run it more than once until is stops collapsing rows with original sort order.  a sort of recursive solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

1. Convert the items of `start_date` and `end_date` from `str` type into `datetime` type so that they can be processed as date objects. This is important to prevent date comparisons based on its string value which would lead incorrectly to e.g. `"01/01/2021" < "12/31/2020"` when it is actually the opposite.
2. Zip the `cust`, `start_date`, and `end_date` into a list.
3. Sort the list in [lexicographical order](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types). This means that it will sort the list primarily by `cust`. All items with the same `cust` would be sorted by `start_date`. All items with the same `cust` and `start_date` would be sorted by `end_date`.
4. Iterate each item in the sorted list.

   a. If the current item is for a different `cust` than the previous item, create a new item.

   b. If the current item is for the same `cust` but is not in the range of the previous item, create a new item.

   c. If the current item is for the same `cust` and is in the range of the previous item, merge it with the previous item.
5. Create the dataframe

**Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import pandas as pd


# Original data
cust = ['CUST123', 'CUST123', 'CUST123', 'CUST123', 'CUST456', 'CUST456']
start_date = ['01/01/2021','01/07/2021','01/15/2021','02/02/2021','01/05/2021','01/16/2021']
end_date = ['01/11/2021','01/14/2021','01/31/2021','02/28/2021','01/15/2021','01/31/2021']

# To be able to sort the dates, convert them to datetime objects
start_date = [datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%m/%d/%Y') for dt_str in start_date]
end_date = [datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%m/%d/%Y') for dt_str in end_date]

# Sort by cust. For equal custs, sort then by start_date. For equal start dates, sort then by end_date.
sorted_cust_dates = sorted(zip(cust, start_date, end_date))

# Create new items or merge to previous item if in same cust and if in range.
merged_cust_dates = []
for current_cust, current_start_date, current_end_date in sorted_cust_dates:
    if len(merged_cust_dates) == 0 or current_cust != merged_cust_dates[-1][0]:
        # Create a new item if this is the first loop or if the cust is different from the previous cust
        merged_cust_dates.append([current_cust, current_start_date, current_end_date])
    elif current_start_date <= merged_cust_dates[-1][2] + timedelta(days=1):
        # Merge the the current item to the previous item if in range
        merged_cust_dates[-1][2] = max(merged_cust_dates[-1][2], current_end_date)
    else:
        # Create a new item otherwise
        merged_cust_dates.append([current_cust, current_start_date, current_end_date])

# Create the dataframe object
df = pd.DataFrame(merged_cust_dates, columns = ['cust', 'start_date', 'end_date'])
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
      cust start_date   end_date
0  CUST123 2021-01-01 2021-01-31
1  CUST123 2021-02-02 2021-02-28
2  CUST456 2021-01-05 2021-01-31
```

Should you need to change the format of the string date, use [datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime).

Answer (score 0):

Following works exactly as intended:

```
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

cust = ['CUST123', 'CUST123', 'CUST123', 'CUST123', 'CUST456', 'CUST456', 'CUST123']
start_date = ['01/01/2021','01/07/2021','01/15/2021','02/02/2021','01/05/2021','01/16/2021', '02/03/2021']
end_date = ['01/11/2021','01/14/2021','01/31/2021','02/28/2021','01/15/2021','01/31/2021', '03/31/2021']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(cust, start_date, end_date)), columns = ['cust', 'start_date', 'end_date'])
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])

# Sort values so we always have date ranges incrementing
df.sort_values("start_date", axis = 0, ascending = True,
                 inplace = True, na_position ='last')

# Helper class                 
class DateRange:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        
    def __contains__(self, value):
        return self.start <= value <= self.end
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.start) + " - " + str(self.end)

subs = {k: [] for k in set(cust)}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # if subs[k] empty fill in first Date Range
    if len(subs[row[0]]) == 0:
        subs[row[0]].append(DateRange(row[1], row[2]))
    else:
        noMatch = True
        # iterate over all available date ranges to see if the following fits
        for x in subs[row[0]]:
            if row[1] in x or row[2] in x or row[1] == x.end + timedelta(1):
                noMatch = False
                if row[1] < x.start:
                    x.start = row[1]
                if row[2] > x.end:
                    x.end = row[2]
        # if noMatch found it could be unique Date Range
        if noMatch:
            subs[row[0]].append(DateRange(row[1], row[2]))
                
for k, v in subs.items():
    for i in v:
        print(k, str(i))
```

Comment: This looks like it works.  I have a question though.  How would I modify this if I wanted to get ranges by cust and another column as well (for example service_tier from my updated example)?

Comment: It's already by cust, `subs = {k: [] for k in set(cust)}` this creates a dictionary which later gets filled with date ranges. You can create a dictionary with tuple keys like `(CUST123, "Service_Tier_1") : [list of date ranges]`. Other way is to add another attribute to `class DateRange` and modify methods to accommodate new attribute.