# groupby and compare timestamps in each group pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

i have the following pandas dataframe:

```
id |       start         |        end         |
---|---------------------|--------------------|
TA | 2022-05-20 06:30:36 | 2022-05-20 09:58:52|
TA | 2022-05-20 08:47:13 | 2022-05-20 08:57:47|
TA | 2022-05-20 08:44:11 | 2022-05-20 10:15:14|
TA | 2022-06-10 07:45:11 | 2022-06-10 10:15:14|
TA | 2022-06-10 07:55:11 | 2022-06-10 11:15:14|
BA | 2022-05-24 08:48:12 | 2022-05-24 10:57:27|
BA | 2022-05-24 10:48:29 | 2022-05-24 12:08:54|
RG | 2022-05-31 07:57:26 | 2022-05-31 08:09:46|
RG | 2022-05-31 08:06:50 | 2022-05-31 08:08:49|
RG | 2022-05-31 08:07:51 | 2022-05-31 08:18:37|
```

for each id I want to compare if the start timestamp is contained between the start and end timestamps and if it is contained then i take the lowest timestamp value from start col and the highest value from end col. The resulting dataframe will look as follows:

```
id |       start         |        end         |
---|---------------------|--------------------|
TA | 2022-05-20 06:30:36 | 2022-05-20 10:15:14|
TA | 2022-06-10 07:45:11 | 2022-06-10 11:15:14|
BA | 2022-05-24 08:48:12 | 2022-05-24 12:08:54|
RG | 2022-05-31 07:57:26 | 2022-05-31 08:18:37|
```

There might be rows where timestamps may not be contained/overlap in a group and those will be remain as they are but those that overlap as in the above example will be reduced and grouped. Can anyone suggest an optimal way in python to achieve this?

**Update**
Data is sorted by *id* and *start*.

Comment: Provide an example of non-overlapping values. Right now it's not obvious what do you mean by _is contained between the start and end_. What is start? what is end? Add the code to produce particularly difficult data on which obvious approaches like `df.groupby('id').agg({'start': min, 'end': max})` do not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge consecutive and overlapping date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68714898/merge-consecutive-and-overlapping-date-ranges)

Comment: @Vitalizzare added example rows for non-overlapping for TA. The added rows do overlap on the same date with time interval intersecting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a way and want to share it here for others with similar issues:

```py
# Initialize variables to store the current interval for each group
current_group = None
current_start = None
current_end = None

# Lists to store the resulting data
result_groups = []
result_start = []
result_end = []

# Iterate through the DataFrame
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    group = row['id']
    start = row['start']
    end = row['end']
    
    # If the group changes, start a new interval
    if group != current_group:
        current_group = group
        current_start = start
        current_end = end
    else:
        # Check if the start time is within the current interval
        if start <= current_end:
            # Update the end time if the current row's end time is greater
            current_end = max(current_end, end)
        else:
            # Save the current interval and start a new one
            result_groups.append(current_group)
            result_start.append(current_start)
            result_end.append(current_end)
            current_start = start
            current_end = end

# Save the last interval
result_groups.append(current_group)
result_start.append(current_start)
result_end.append(current_end)

# Create a new DataFrame with the results
result_df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': result_groups, 'Start_Time': result_start, 'End_Time': result_end})
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your data is already sorted first by _id_ and then by _start_?

Comment: yes, you are right @Vitalizzare

Answer (score 0):

In case of data sorted by `"id"` and `"start"` we can create additional cumulative maximum end column, then split data where either a new group id appear or the start data is bigger then the previous cumulative max end, and in each obtained part get the first start date and the last cumulative max end date as aggregated values:

```
df['cummax_end'] = df.groupby('id', as_index=False, sort=False)['end'].cummax()
is_new_group = df['id'] != df['id'].shift()
is_new_interval = df['start'] > df['cummax_end'].shift()
grouper = (is_new_group | is_new_interval).cumsum()

answer = df.groupby(grouper).agg({
    'id': 'first', 
    'start': 'first', 
    'cummax_end': 'last'
})
```

On the test data

```
data = '''\
id |       start         |        end         |
---|---------------------|--------------------|
TA | 2022-05-20 06:30:36 | 2022-05-20 09:58:52|
TA | 2022-05-20 08:47:13 | 2022-05-20 08:57:47|
TA | 2022-05-20 08:44:11 | 2022-05-20 10:15:14|
TA | 2022-06-10 07:45:11 | 2022-06-10 10:15:14|
TA | 2022-06-10 07:55:11 | 2022-06-10 11:15:14|
BA | 2022-05-24 08:48:12 | 2022-05-24 10:57:27|
BA | 2022-05-24 10:48:29 | 2022-05-24 12:08:54|
RG | 2022-05-31 07:57:26 | 2022-05-31 08:09:46|
RG | 2022-05-31 08:06:50 | 2022-05-31 08:08:49|
RG | 2022-05-31 08:07:51 | 2022-05-31 08:18:37|
'''

df = pd.read_table(
    StringIO(data), 
    sep = ' *\| *', 
    skiprows=[1],
    engine='python',
    usecols=[0,1,2], 
    parse_dates=[1, 2],
)
```

we get the output

```
>>> print(answer.to_string(index=False))
id               start          cummax_end
TA 2022-05-20 06:30:36 2022-05-20 10:15:14
TA 2022-06-10 07:45:11 2022-06-10 11:15:14
BA 2022-05-24 08:48:12 2022-05-24 12:08:54
RG 2022-05-31 07:57:26 2022-05-31 08:18:37
```